# Is there a way to make a page anchor from a wordpress menu item?

Tags: wordpress

I'd like to add a custom anchor link to my wordpress main menu so that if the user clicks, it will jump to a certain part of the page.

Comment: What about my solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create an anchor on the page wherever you want, eg a post about how to make pickled onions:

```
<a href="#pickled-onions">Pickled Onions</a>
```

Then just insert #pickled-onions into the custom url field for the menu on that page. When you click the custom menu link it will jump to the anchor.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Plugin for the same, for ex:

```
https://wordpress.org/plugins/easy-smooth-scroll-links/
```